# How do I attach varbinary(max) data from SQL to my SMTPMessage in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, smtp

I have a **varbinary(max)** column in my **SQL** server containing binary that looks like the following:

```
  0x255044462D312E340D0A25E2E3CFD30D...
```

I want to retrieve this value in a powershell so that I can run logic that sends out an email.

```
#Get the attachment binary into a variable from sql server
$Query = "SELECT AttachmentBinary FROM [dbo].MyFiles"
$e= Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance $server (etc.etc.)
```

Running $e.Attachmentbinary in powershell gives me a list of decimal numbers, which I assume is how powershell displays the binary:

```
37
80
68
70
45
(and so on)
```

The problem now is that when I prepare the file and send the email..

```
$contentStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$e.Attachmentbinary)
$MailAttachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($contentStream, "application/pdf")
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($MailAttachment)
```

.. It leaves sends me a 1kb file. That is to say,

```
$e.AttachmentBinary.Length #Returns 1024 for some reason..
```

I know for sure the binary data in the database is correct. The problem seems to be in the second part when adding the attachment.

How can this be corrected?

Comment: Looking at the [constructor overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=net-5.0#overloads) for the MemoryStream class, you want `System.IO.MemoryStream($e.Attachmentbinary)`. The comma there makes it use the overload with two parameters which wants the byte buffer as the first param and the second a Boolean (writable)

Comment: P.S. you may need to explicitely cast the `$e.Attachmentbinary` to `[Byte[]]$e.Attachmentbinary`

Comment: @Theo your solution worked, but I also had to increase  -MaxBinaryLength 78680 for my  Invoke-Sqlcmd command.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `tsql`. Please remove the the tag which lead the wrong people here and waste the time

Answer (score 3):

The `Invoke-Sqlcmd` needs a `-MaxBinaryLength` value, as the default size of 1024 (1KB) may be to small for the varbinary.

The resulting array $e.Attachmentbinary  needs to be cast to binary explicitly, as @Theo suggested.

```
[Byte[]]$e.Attachmentbinary
```